# Should Extbase Persistence TypoScript always be loaded globally?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

Imagine a multi-site TYPO3 installation. One of those sites uses an Extension (loads the extension's TypoScript) that modifies the `config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes` config for `GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News`. Other sites also use News, but without including that Extension doing the modification.

The problem that you will run into is that the DataMaps are cached globally - so after clearing the cache it depends which site will be called first and its extbase persistence configuration will be cached, possibly breaking the functionality of the other sites.

To get around this problem I started to move DataMapper related TypoScript into a separate TypoScript file `ExtbasePersistence.typoscript` and load it globally in ext_localconf.php:

`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScript('myext', 'setup', '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:myext/Configuration/TypoScript/ExtbasePersistence.typoscript">');`

My question is: Why is this not best practise and done in every extension? Or what am I doing wrong that I seem to be the only one running into that problem?

Edit: From my point of view this would mean that also core extensions (such as `extbase`) MUST load their DataMapper related TypoScript globally.

Comment: Seems for me, that the DataMap Cache is buggy. This handling of class maps in TypoScript is a bad thing per se if you ask me, because it should not be dependant on the site context which class to load. These things should rather be handled via global configuration that can not be changed by editors on several pages

Answer (score 0):

Extbase does load this globally via https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/extbase/ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript

This file is auto loaded by TYPO3 on a global scope, this is also best practice, as far as I know.

Each Extension can add this file, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#reserved-file-names